# XCode: Commit failed in SVN : No space left on device

Tags: xcode, svn, memory, commit, commit-message

**Hi,**

I am committing my project in SVN using XCode. I do it successfully for quite a few months. But suddenly today, while committing, it is showing the following error :

> #### The working copy "Classes" failed to commit files.
>
> svn: Commit failed (details below)
> svn: Can't open '/usr/local/repos/Iphone/my_svn_repo/db/tempfile.tmp' : No space left on device

Is it a memory issue on the svn side or in the Iphone I am using ? How to avoid it ?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either your local disk or svn servers disk `/usr` partition is full.  This prevents the svn command from creating a necessary temp file, therefore the commit fails.

`No space left on device` is refering to the system device (hard drive - not iOS device) at `/dev/hda1` (or whichever `/dev/[hs]d[abcd..][1-..]`).

```
svn: Commit failed (details below) svn: Can't open '/usr/local/repos/Iphone/my_svn_repo/db/tempfile.tmp' : No space left on device
```

Run `df` and `mv` files off `/usr` to clean out space on either your local disk or the svn server and run the `svn ci ...` again.

Comment: **No space left on device is refering to the system device (hard drive - not iOS device)** was answer to my problem

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. Using df -h I found that one of the mounted servers where we keep the repositories was full. I cleaned up space on this server and it was working again. Hope this helps.

[image]